# Access to functions in required modules defined in the calling module

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

How can you call a function within a required module but defined in the main program?

Main.js:

```
var http = require('http');
var aFunc = function() {return 1;}
var bFunc = require('./bFunc').bFunc;
var cFunc = function() {console.log(aFunc() + bFunc()); } // should equal 3.

httpServer = http.createServer(cFunc()).listen(80);
```

bFunc.js:

```
var bFunc = function() {return aFunc() + aFunc()};
exports.bFunc = bFunc;
```

I don't want to define (copy) aFunc in bFunc, nor do I want to put aFunc into its own file (aFunc.js).  Is there a way to access aFunc in bFunc by referring back to the main program that "required" bFunc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to pass `afunc` to `bfunc`:

```
// main.js
var cFunc = function() {console.log(aFunc() + bFunc(afunc)); }

// bfunc.js
var bFunc = function(f) {return f() + f()};
```

JavaScript has *lexical scope*.

Comment: Well, you could create a global variable. But that breaks encapsulation.

Comment: @ChrisGciso: if it feels like your're having to go against the grain, you probably are...

Comment: But isn't main.js its own scope when run using node.js?  Does bFunc not have access to that scope?

Comment: Yes they have their own scope. No, a module doesn't have access to another modules scope (and neither to the main script). Why would it? Encapsulation is a good thing.

Comment: It seems like since main.js is requiring bFunc that the called module should have access to the calling module.  I understand what you're saying.  It's just confusing to me since in normal (not using node.js) javascript a function defined in another function has access to everything in the parent (calling) function's scope.

Comment: @ChrisGciso: That's no different here. `bFunc` is **not** *defined* inside `main.js`, it's defined in a separate module. Imagine you have `function foo() { }; function bar() { var baz = 'something'; foo(); }`. Here, `foo` doesn't have access to `baz` either, because `foo` is not defined inside `bar` (where `bar` gets the reference from `foo` doesn't matter, I could also define a `require` function that simply looks up global variables).

Comment: Even if `bFunc` had access to the variables defined in `main.js`, making `bFunc` *depending* on those variables would be bad design since it creates an implicit interface.

Comment: I understand now.  bFunc is not defined in the main program.  It's defined seperately and just referenced in the main program.  "Require" doesn't bring the code from bFunc.js into main.js. It's no different than if I defined these functions one after another. Thank you Felix.

Comment: Related/Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027866/call-function-of-app-js-from-within-module-in-node-js?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20193874/how-can-i-share-an-object-between-my-modules?rq=1